# Report on Logical Errors

Tags: runtime-error

I recently encountered a **logical error** in one of our systems and our management wants a report on this. What do we call this kind of report? Also I would like to know if there is any resource available on-line that can help me write this report.

I have already prepared change management, got it approved and made the necessary correction to the application.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe, this should be incident management report as well. This error happened unexpectedly and affected the daily operation of the business.

ITIL Templates:
http://wiki.en.it-processmaps.com/index.php/ITIL-Checklists

Comment: Thanks @user4318985, I was able to write an incident report.